# How to make HTTP client requests with Deno

Tags: deno

I'm playing around with Deno but I can't find the standard HTTP client.

I also googled "deno http client" which gives me https://deno.land/x/std/http/client/, but the link is broken. Something was indexed by Google and later removed from the repo.

```
404 - Not Found
This file or directory could not be found.
```

I found 3rd party libraries [soxa](https://github.com/fakoua/soxa) and [deno-http](https://github.com/lenkan/deno-http) but I am looking for something standard.

Is there a standard HTTP client for Deno that I am missing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`deno` implements a variety of [Web APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API). To make an HTTP request in `deno` you use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

```js
const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
const data = await res.json();
```

Web APIs are exposed to the global scope the same way they're in the browser. `deno` aims to be browser compatible whenever it's possible.

You'll also be able to use:

- [`FormData`](https://doc.deno.land/https/github.com/denoland/deno/releases/latest/download/lib.deno.d.ts#FormData)
- [`Headers`](https://doc.deno.land/https/github.com/denoland/deno/releases/latest/download/lib.deno.d.ts#Headers)
- [`cache`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) (`.put` & `.match` supported)

Comment: The official `deno` document about this: https://deno.land/manual/runtime/web_platform_apis